# How to access one module service in another module service (Liferay 7)

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

Suppose, I have two service builder Modules (Let's namely call it "**First**" and "**Second**"). Now I want to use "First" service in "Second" ???

So in "Second" build.gradle (of both Second-service and Second-api) I added below entry

```
compileOnly project(":modules:First:First-api")
```

Also tried with:

```
compile project(":modules:First:First-api")
```

But it's showing *Unable to find module* error

Any Suggestion ?

~Regards

Chandan

Comment: are you using the Liferay workspace?

Comment: Yes I am using Liferay Workspace

Comment: Hi @ChandanPrakashSharma, have you solved it? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like adding the dependency in **"Second"** project *build.gradle* file.

Comment: Yes I added the dependency in Second project build.gradle as you can see in my post